# How to detect a keypress *before* swing components and loaded / initialized

Tags: java, swing, awt, keypress

My application needs to detect if the `CONTROL` key is depressed early in the startup and change the startup sequence if it is.

What I need to do is very similar to how `MouseInfo` can get the pointer position (without waiting for an event to go through the AWT processing mechanism).

```
    MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

Does something like this exist for the keyboard? I.e. detect if a certain key is depressed **right now** ?

Please note that registering listeners does not work for me, since once the mouse events start processing then it is already "too late" - my application has already started up and I need to head off certain operations during startup.

```
    // note: this doesn't work. the event is received AFTER app has started
    final AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (!fired && ((KeyEvent) event).isControlDown()) {
                fired = true;
                System.out.println(event);
                dontDoSomethingHeavyDuringStartup();
            }
        }
    };
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Comment: Java and its GUIs can react to Key/MouseEvents only if is container already visible on the screen, you have to bothering with transparent / translucent contianer (don't forget to add some kind of Timer - terminating an aplication), must be focusable for KeyEvents, then is possible to call (with requiered parameters) another jre with separate jvm instance...

Comment: not knowing your use case, but maybe start-up parameters will do the same job?

Comment: Yes, nice idea, and in an ideal world yes, but I'm actually writing a plugin for an established product and I don't have access to startup parameters via the program architecture.